# The system cannot find the file specified : java

Tags: java

```
String pathFromdb="F:";
String pdFpath=pathFromdb+"/version/pdf/"+pdfName;

String pdfversion = pdFpath;

System.out.println("pdfversion" + pdfversion);
System.out.println(date + " pdf from db" + pdfversion);
List<PdfReader> list_r = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
list_r.add(new PdfReader(new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfversion))));
```

Here pdfName get from db, and I created the exact PDF document in the folder location, but I'm getting the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\version\pdf\611a0a3f6f14d302af1686f2 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.nic.eoffice.ci.dao.PetitoinServiceDao.GetPetitionReport(PetitoinServiceDao.java:1225)
    at com.nic.eoffice.controller.PetitionController.GetPetitionReport(PetitionController.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
```

Comment: how come your path doesn't have an extension? You understand that file and file.pdf aren't the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String pathFromdb="F:";
String pdFpath=pathFromdb+"/version/pdf/"+pdfName+".pdf";

String pdfversion = pdFpath;

System.out.println("pdfversion" + pdfversion);
System.out.println(date + " pdf from db" + pdfversion);
List<PdfReader> list_r = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
list_r.add(new PdfReader(new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfversion))));
```

Comment: if this solved your issue, accept the answer. that way people can see the question is solved

Comment: @Stultuske You can only accept your own answer after a timeout (24 hours IIRC).